# How can I set my php variables in Nexmo code

Tags: php, api, key, sms, vonage

I an setting up a website to send SMS automatically by API key Nexmo. But whene I add my variables into the Nexmo code, this one not work. How can I add my variables please?

I added my php variables to the Nexmo SMS default code but no result, but whene  I trayed there code the stuff work fine

my file phone.php , with $row["phone_number"]=212981416807 at this exemple

```
$text1 = "Hello";
$text2 = " this is my company";
$MyNexmoID_Account = "3896321";
$MyNexmoAPI_Key = "yhg784frds78jkim";
$to = $row["phone_number"];
$from = "my company";
$text = "$text1 $text2";


// Code to Send SMS with Code Recharge ------
    require_once "vendor/autoload.php";
        //composer require nexmo/client;
    $basic  = new \Nexmo\Client\Credentials\Basic('$MyNexmoID_Account', '$MyNexmoAPI_Key');
    $client = new \Nexmo\Client($basic);

    $message = $client->message()->send([
    'to' => '$to',
    'from' => '$from',
    'text' => '$text'
    ]);
    if ($message && $client && $basic){echo " Recharge Code Sent Correctlly.";}else{echo "Failed! Recharge Code Not Sent.";}
// End Code to Send SMS with Code Recharge -----
```

This is default Nexmo code:

```
    require_once "vendor/autoload.php";
        //composer require nexmo/client;
    $basic  = new \Nexmo\Client\Credentials\Basic('3896321', 'yhg784frds78jkim');
    $client = new \Nexmo\Client($basic);

    $message = $client->message()->send([
    'to' => '212981416807',
    'from' => 'Nexmo',
    'text' => 'Hello Nexmo'
    ]);
```

Comment: Do not post your API keys anywhere on the internet, this is how you get hacked!

Comment: thank you I know that this is why I use uncorrect API key in my question

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to quote variables. Try this:

```
$message = $client->message()->send([
'to' => $to,
'from' => $from,
'text' => $text
]);
```

Comment: I think that there is something else which is wrong. help me please.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you have corrected this but do check your country code, I had a similar error with variable (also do listen to Michael Heap), where the hard code for the US phone number was 19091234567 and my database number was 9091234567. Unlike Twilio, Nexmo needs the country code. Hope it helps.